# NodeJS exports not defined in external JS file

Tags: node.js, express

I am calling a function from an external JS file in my routes file. So, I am trying to export a function from my `externalFile.js` file. However, when I run the node server, it throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` . `externalFile.js` is in `public/javascripts/` and the route files is in `routes/`.

External file (`externalFile.js`):

```
exports.capsolvingComplete = function (stdout){
    //Received, display text and hide the spinner, put check in place.
    $('#capsolv-complete').css("display", "block")
    $('#capsolv-output').text(stdout);
}
```

Route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var script = require('../public/javascripts/externalFile.js')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'CapSolv' });
});

router.post('/file-upload', function(req, res){
    script.capsolvingComplete("HI");
    res.end("success");
})

module.exports = router;
```

Thank you for your help! Bit of a node noob here.

Comment: Even if `capsolvingComplete` worked, how were you expecting to use jquery inside node.js to update the client during a POST?

Comment: Is manipulating the DOM on the server-side generally frowned upon?

Comment: You can't manipulate the client's DOM from node like that. If you want to update the client on upload progress and such, you will need to use something like websockets/socket.io/sockjs/etc. to push messages to the client which then update the DOM.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. If I want to post to `file-upload` through client-side javascript, do I post to `/file-upload`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, mscdex is right. Anything you require in Node is designed to run on the server, and doesn't have access to the browser's DOM.

I would recommend building a REST API that accepts the file upload, stores it, and returns a JSON object containing metadata: i.e. where the file was stored, size, etc., and let your client deal with that.